# Re-sizing with a relative position div

Tags: jquery, html, css, jscript

I've been playing around with this a bit and can't quite figure it out so...

I have what is essentially a sliding sidebar.

The initial state looks like this.

```
#sidebar {
    position: fixed,
    width: 200px
}
```

the other state is:

```
#sidebar {
    position: fixed,
    width: 200px,
    left: -190px
}
```

I want another  to be to the right of this filling the remaining space on the screen.  This should also be dynamic so when the #sidebar is toggled, it will re-size to fill the space at all times.

Note:  The css changes to the #sidebar is animated with $.animate as well, so it should re-size as the sidebar is re-sizing.

Is there a good way to do this with CSS.  Or, is there a good jscript/jquery library for a sliding in/out sidebar.  I looked but could not find one, so I started rolling my own.

The only other way I can think of is manually re-sizing the other  with jscript, while re-positioning the #sidebar.  But that seems over kill.

Comment: I think it could be done with CSS using form elements to maintain state but I would rather manage the UI with Javascript.  Here is a CSS example of a horizontal accordion in CSS http://jsfiddle.net/m_raffaele/Fzuz7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example:

CSS:

```
#sidebar
{
    position: fixed;
    width: 200px;
    background-color:#9cf;
    left:0;
}
#sidebar.tucked { left: -190px; }
#content
{
    margin-left:200px;
}
#content.tucked { margin-left:10px; }
```

Javascript:

```
$(function()
{
    $('#sidebar').on("click", function()
    {
        $('#sidebar, #content').toggleClass("tucked", 1000);
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w9aWp/

Answer (score 1):

I've put together this fiddle based on a similar project I worked on: http://jsfiddle.net/DrdHJ/

Basically I just have two columns:

```
<div id="sidebar">

    <a class="resize" data-width="300">Large</a>
    <br>
    <a class="resize" data-width="200">Small</a>

</div>

<div id="main"></div>
```

`#sidebar` is your 'sliding' column and `#main` is your main block which contains content.

Then for CSS I have the following:

```
html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; }

#sidebar { 
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-color: red;
}

#main {
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

The important thing to notice is that `margin-left` on `#main` is what keeps in in place.

Then for JavaScript I have the following:

```
$('.resize').on('click',function(){

    var width = $(this).data('width');

    $('#sidebar').css('width',width+'px');
    $('#main').css('margin-left',width+'px');

});
```

Which listens for the event to resize and then adjusts the width of the `#sidebar` and the margin-left offset of the `#main` based on the `data-width` attribute of the link clicked. This could obviously be tweaked to replace the `css()` with `animate`.